# How do i pass number to middleware "can" in Laravel Authorization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

based on documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-middleware

```
use App\Post;

Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');
```

the 'post' in 'can:update,post' is variable passed from '{post}'.

im trying to use **middleware('can:update,1')**. its not working. maybe its search for '$1' variable, how to pass number '1' to 'can' middleware?

**update** this is the gate:

```
    Gate::define('update', function ($user, $role){
        $id = $user->id;
        $roles = $user::find($id)->roles()->get();
        $roleid = $roles[0]->pivot->role_id;
        //above code just for get role id, and $role_id is 1
       return $roleid === $role;
    });
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  What do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: @kerrin, oh my bad, the result is **This action is unauthorized**, im trying controller helper method, its working, but not with middleware.

Comment: can you show your update form?

Comment: You can access the parameter inside middlware with `$request->route('post');` without passing any parameter !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you don't have Policy created for Post.

You can create by command:

```
php artisan make:policy PostPolicy --model=Post
```

and then implement method update in that policy.

Comment: Hello @highsolutions, sorry for late reply, i use "anonymous?" policy. please check updated question above, thank you

Comment: But @tonywei you should use `Policy` for this operation. `Can` is connected to policies not gates.

Answer (score 2):

I to had this same problem so I did some digging into the 'can' middleware (Which maps to `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize`)

Once in the class we see the following code

```
 /**
     * Get the model to authorize.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|string
     */
    protected function getModel($request, $model)
    {
        if ($this->isClassName($model)) {
            return trim($model);
        } else {
            return $request->route($model, null) ?:
                ((preg_match("/^['\"](.*)['\"]$/", trim($model), $matches)) ? $matches[1] : null);
        }
    }
```

What this means is...

- If our string passed in is a class name then return that class name
- If it is not a class name then...

  - 1 Try to get it from the route, then return the route param
  - 2 Try to get the model from the string via the regex `"/^['\"](.*)['\"]$/"`

So now lets say we have the middleware call of 
`$this->middleware(sprintf("can:create,%s,%s", User::class, Role::SUPPORT));`

This will not work because the `Role::SUPPORT` does not match the regex

To match it we simply need to place the `Role::SUPPORT` into quotes.

TAKE NOTE OF THE "'" around the second %s
`$this->middleware(sprintf("can:create,%s,'%s'", User::class, Role::SUPPORT));`

To answer your question specifically, quote your '1' value

```
middleware("can:update,'1'").
```